ps2pdf produces hundreds of lines of output, but works
In my case, ps2pdf processing produces hundreds of lines of the type
Page 0 NumUniqueObjects 20
Page 1 NumUniqueObjects 5
...
Shared Object group 624, NumObjects 1
Shared Object group 625, NumObjects 1
Shared Object group 626, NumObjects 1

What is going on? Everything goes well, the output is what I want.
Can I avoid the lines?
Well, I found out that they come from the flag
-dFastWebView=true

Can I leave this flag out? I "inherited" it, taking
it over from somebody without knowing what it does.
What does it do?

You can easily leave this option off (and I would). The FastWebView option causes GhostScript to optimize the PDF, making loading faster at the expense of file size.
If the lines of output bother you, you can redirect them to the null device, assuming you are certain everything is running correctly. Leaving off that option will probably make all of them go away, though.

OK, thank you very much.
